# Exchangeable filtration $\mathcal{E}_n$ is the same as $\sigma(S_n,X_{n+1},\dots)$?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

It should be a really intuitive conclusion but I kind of missing in the detail treatment.

Suppose we have $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and equipped it with the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{B}_{\infty}$ generated by finite rectangles, i.e. $\times_{i=1}^{n}(a_i,b_i], \forall n$. Let $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,)\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a general element and $x_1,x_2,\dots$ be the coordinate map.

Now the exchangeable filtration is that for each $n\geq 1$, let $\mathcal{E}_n$ consists of all sets $B\in \mathcal{B}$ s.t. the indicator $1_B(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ satisfies for any permutation $\sigma$ in $[n]$(the set of $n!$ permutations),
$$1_B(x_1,x_2,\dots)=1_B(x_{\sigma(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)},x_{n+1},\dots).$$

So my question is,  is it true that $\mathcal{E}_n=\sigma(s_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\dots)$
where $s_n=x_1+\dots+x_n$.

Since $s_n,x_{n+1},\dots \in \mathcal{E}_n$, one direction of inclusion is easy. I wonder the other direction. I think it is a question that how rich $\sigma(s_n)$ is.

Comment: Lots of $\mathcal{E}_n$-measurable functions are not $\sigma(s_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\dots)$-measurable. For an example, consider $m_n=\max\{x_k\mid k\leqslant n\}$.